# angular-summernote: Cursor jumps to end of text while typing in codeview mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, summernote

we use summernote 0.8.1 together with angular-summernote v0.8.1 and angularjs 1.7.9.
While editing a text in codeview mode, the cursor unpredictably jumps to the end of the text.
This happens with chrome and firefox. I did not test it with ie.

I managed to reproduce this strange behavior in the advanced features example "use ngModel to synchronize the value" on http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/n8dt4/322/embedded/result.html

```
<summernote ng-model="text"></summernote>
```

In order to reproduce the behavior ...
- Write some text in the wysiwyg mode
- Then switch to codeview mode
- Type in random chars somewhere in the middle of the text
- after an unpredictable number of chars the cursor suddenly jumps to the end of the text

Has anyone out here ever noticed this strange behavior and can suggest a workaround?

Kind regards,
Sylvain